# Serverless App Sync Plugin Resolver Configuration

Tags: aws-appsync, serverless-appsync-plugin

I am trying to get a serverless app sync resolver deployed and I am following the [documentation](https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin/blob/master/doc/resolvers.md) on Github under "Inline Datasources". The documentation suggests that the following should be enough to create a resolver with a lambda datasource inline:

The following snippet shows the example:

```
appSync:
  resolvers:
    Query.user:
      dataSource:
        type: 'AWS_LAMBDA'
        config:
          function:
            timeout: 30
            handler: 'functions/getUser.handler'
```

When I try to follow this example (shown below):

```
resolvers:
    Query.get_data:
      dataSource:
        type: AWS_LAMBDA
        config:
          function:
            timeout: 30
            handler: "functions/get_data.handler"
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid AppSync Configuration:
     at appSync/resolvers/Query.get_data: must have required property 'functions'
     at appSync/resolvers: contains invalid resolver definitions
```

I am not sure what this error really means, if someone has got a working example of this I would appreciate seeing where I have gone wrong as its a really simple example and is pretty much straight from the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this and it might prove helpful for someone else, I was missing something in the docs which is not shown in the example, the default type is pipeline resolver which means it does require the functions block.

Adding the `kind` property to `resolvers.Query.my_query` in my sls config resolved this issue:

```
kind: UNIT
```